# cannot reshare facebook page post if posted using api and as a page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook api to share a link on the facebook page as a page. Everything working perfectly except resharing the same post. If i reshare the same post, it is just sharing the link of the post rather than sharing the complete post. here is the link that i am using to share.

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=458358780877780&link=https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&name=Facebook%20Dialogs&caption=Reference%20Documentation&description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&redirect_uri=https://mighty-lowlands-6381.herokuapp.com/&to=Publicsugarzzz&from=Publicsugarzzz